# Database change notification app

Tags: java, php, android, database, web-services

I'm about to embark upon writing an android app which notifies the phone's user when an external mySQL DB is updated (add only) with a ticket so that the user can check if the ticket requires his attention (an attempt to reduce the buildup of tickets that he has to trawl through).

From my research, most questions suggest using a PHP web service with my program (written in java) and definitely/maybe/definitely not/it's deprecated using SQLNotification to fire the event. I've also seen something about some bloke called JSON and the brands of SOAP he uses.

What I've been unable to figure out is how all of these frameworks/toolkits/services/things work together.

My question is in two parts:

1. Is SQLNotification usable? If not, is there a simple way to check for changes (beyond the obvious answer of polling)
2. How does everything (SOAP, JSON, web service, app) fit together and have I missed anything on the frameworks front (Heard mentions of spring, hibernate, tomcat).

On my experience, I'm relatively fluent in Java, understand the basics of MySQL, am a beginner in PHP and haven't written for android before.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: if you need a push notification why don't you create a `GCM` from the server side

Comment: @DevZer0 Because I didn't click that button on the index page because it didn't sound like what I wanted. Is this in place of the web server?

Comment: This would be ideal because you can trigger to queue the message as the database insert happens as part of the server code. So you don't have to poll server continuously.

Comment: @DevZer0 So based upon what I understand, The DB sends the message directly to the app, removing the need for anything other than the java code in the app which gets the message and processes it?

Comment: First step would be to clarify your needs. Implementing a push situation that would immediately notify on the phone sounds like a nice idea, but do you really need it? You would have an app on your phone with an ever connected Websocket (or whatever you will be using) that will consume battery. What are the needs of your users? Polling sounds like "oldish" but does not mean it's a bad idea. Why not use some service that the phone already has (like Gmail)? If you will use the phone only for notification and not for working with the tickets, you might be trying to build something too big...

Comment: @Martin The app's user currently has the problem of coming into the office and having to trawl through 50 or so tickets tuesday to friday and 200-300 tickets on a monday. The app would enable him to note which tickets required his attention splitting the time from reading 300 e-mails split among his regular e-mails to a couple of seconds every now and then. Upon speaking with the user, he wants it as a separate e-mail like client with the title, a numeric representation of the problem severity and the summary. Polling every now and then is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you have provided, seems like you have different options:

- Push

  - If you want to go the push way, you will need some central architecture that can take notifications from the database and immediately send them to connected clients. It's not that easy to build such a scheme, would only recommend it if you really need immediate notification. As a start point, look at this sample: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/
- Pull

  - If you go the pull way (polling), you can have a service working on the phone wich polls every configured time. In that case you will need some stateless service, some simple JSON service would do great.

On both cases, be careful with security, you should secure your channel with ssl and have some decent sort of authentication.

I think a good rule of thumb is saying (it's just based on personal opinion/experience, maybe your decision path has other factors that you have to consider), if your pollig intervals don't need to be lower than 5 minutes, polling will do fine. If you need almost real-time notifications, you can implement the push architecture, but you have to know it will cost more efford to get it working as you have to take care of things like client disconnection, how to handle notifications if a client is not connected, get the real-time notifications from the database, etc.

Hope this helps as a starting point,